# Are there any widespread, modern Java coding conventions?

Tags: java, tabs, coding-style

Sun's "[Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/)" was last updated April 1999.  Ten years later a lot has changed in the language, as well as general usage patterns.  Are there more up to date, widely adopted standards?

Most guidelines omit specifying file encoding and line endings.  Sun recommends mixed tabs and spaces.  The Eclipse IDE defaults to Eclipse's standard, which is tabs only.  The [Maven style guide](http://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html) is spaces only.  Many style guides, such as [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/coding.html), follow Sun's guidelines, but prefer K&R braces instead of [OTBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS).  Each Apache project has it's own style guide, with slight differences between each one.

Comment: I like Joel's take on coding conventions and what they are meant for, but all too often they end up as religion without any critical thought on the why: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Tabs: If you are using any *competent* editor, it can and will easily convert tabs to whatever eye-pleasing # of spaces that you wish for.

For fine-tune alignment of code, use spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't ask what your coding style is, but rather for existing coding standards.

I found the **[European Space Agency Java Coding Standards](ftp://ftp.estec.esa.nl/pub/wm/wme/bssc/Java-Coding-Standards-20050303-releaseA.pdf)** (pdf) ([alt link](http://www.sourceformat.com/pdf/java-coding-standard-bssc.pdf)) which seems up to date and comprehensive, though I'm not sure how widespread the adoption is.

Comment: "Rule 1: Use the Apache Ant tool to automatically build your project."

I guess that means that there are quite a few broken open source projects now. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but this is better than Sun's recommendation of 'GNUmakefile - The preferred name for makefiles.'  As far as standards go, it's a pain to pick up a project where the last developer used Groovy/Ruby/Maven etc.. to build their project.  You can compile your project with awk as far as I care, as long as you also provide or export an ant file.

Answer (score 16):

Four spaces - it's what God uses.

Comment: It's what Sun uses (for the JDK at least).

Comment: Funny, thats what I use too ;).  Seriously though don't worry about file encodings and line endings - I have never heard that come up in a discussion on coding standards.

Comment: That's two spaces too many.

Comment: @Tom H: Sun might *specify* that they use 4 spaces, but if you look at the source it's quite clear that they mix tabs at 8 characters with spaces; either that or the majority of the core lib developers have no sense of what good indentation is.

Comment: @Tom H: Sun used the old default Emacs formatting, that uses four character indenting, but achieves it using tabs for every eight character block, and makes up the difference with four spaces. This dates back to a time where using 1 byte over 8 for two levels of indent (per line) started adding up to real storage space and money.

Comment: Indentation = 4 spaces, but tabs = 8 spaces.  See the official standard at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html

Comment: For a moment I thought he referred to Jon Skeet as God.

Comment: @EdwardFalk You're using a document, that hasn't been updated since 1999, as a reference?

Comment: Has it been superseded? Note also that Eclipse also recognizes the 8-column standard if you go to editor settings and switch to "java conventions"

Answer (score 8):

The only coding standard you really need to follow is that as accepted by your project team.  You might not agree with tabs instead of spaces, but if that is the coding convention of your team, you will do best to follow it.

Comment: In trying to get a team to consensus, it's often quite useful to have a list of common standards, so you can say: "I think we should adopt standard X" or "standard Y is used by many other projects".  Hence the question.

Comment: I agree.  When trying to start a team or build consensus, you are absolutely correct.  Unfortunately, as you point out, your 'list of common standards' often contains conflicts!

Answer (score 6):

Although it may look dated, not much has been added to the core language itself ( the libraries have had a lot of a lot of additions though )

Those I can remember are right now are `enum` and generics, the rest was already there when the document was first written.

- Use 4 spaces always.
- Don't use K&R or Allman: While it is perfectly acceptable for C, C++ and C# it's not always the case for Java (unless the project has explicitly decided to use it ). Using K&R or Allman in Java is visually unpleasant as it would be not to use it in C.
- Use braces always, including single line statements.

Generally speaking try not to mix styles between programming languages. It's like the accent pronunciation in a natural language, you may be understood, you can read and write in it, and have a workable level in the language, but a deficient pronunciation will only annoy the native speakers.

Comment: I feel a lot has changed.  Both in terms of features, and how people use the language.  Evolution is why we have HashMap not Hashmap.  The language now has annotations, static imports, autoboxing, foreach, etc..  I even find it hard to read Java 1.0-1.2 code.  Unicode is common enough that you now find programs with Unicode character in comments and strings.  Items like "GNUmakefile - The preferred name for makefiles. " could probably be removed from the Sun coding standard.

Comment: What?  The official C# conventions say not to use K&R.  In comparison, the official Java conventions allow it.

Comment: @brianegge You're right on that, is Allman style no K&R

Comment: If you are suggesting to **not** use either K&R or Allman in Java, what do you suggest we use?  I have only ever seen those two used in Java.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In K&R you would put the opening brace for a class and a method in a new line. Just put it in the same line. I don't know if that has a name

Answer (score 2):

Ray Ontko has a [Bibliography of Java Coding Standards](http://www.ontko.com/java/java_coding_standards.html).  But it would be difficult to identify any single standard as "widely adopted".

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the one used by default by your IDE's reformatter mechanism.  Will save you a lot of time in the long run.

We enable save actions in Eclipse and tick Format Source so the sources always are reformatted.  This means that a reformat only changes things happened since last time the file was saved.  Is nice in source control history.

You can naturally take your time and define your own format, but it tends to be easier just using the Eclipse standard - it is ok for us.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Elements of Java Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521777682)

Comment: This book is almost as old as Sun's guide.

Comment: +1 This is an outstanding book that is still applicable, despite its age.

Answer (score 0):

Official coding conventions are found at this URL: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score -2):

BSD/Allman is the only decent indent style. It meets the basic rule of curly brackets - if they sit on different lines, they should sit on the same column. Even Horstmann is tolerable compared to K&R.

Always put curly brackets if you code in notepad. Otherwise, due to the auto-indenting features of your IDE, it is useless and annoying.